# What's the real type of int (*T::*)(long);

Tags: c++

This is the sample code:

```
typedef int (T::*t1)(long);
typedef int (*T::*t2)(long);

t1 p1 = NULL;
t2 p2 = NULL;
```

The type t2 get's extra * (by mistake), but this code compile and run OK.
But when t2 is not NULL, it gets error:

```
struct T
{
    int func(long)   {return 0;}
};
t2 p2 = &T::func;
```

```
error: cannot convert ‘int (T::*)(long int)’ to ‘t2’ {aka ‘int (* T::*)(long int)’} in initialization
```

I'm curious, what's the real type of t2?
How can I use t2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eliminate the pointer-to-member bit of syntax (by applying the spiral rule heuristic), and a specific type stands out:

`int (* /* T::*t2 */)(long)` -> `int (*)(long)`.

So `t2` is a pointer to a member of `T`, which is itself a pointer to a free function.

```
int bar(long) { return 0; }

struct T
{
    int (*func) (long) = &bar;
};
t2 p2 = &T::func;
```

Comment: `using t2 = std::type_identity_t<int (*)(long)> T::*;`.